How to display a logo using brand.yml within a Quarto html document?
Using python kernel and running in vscode to render quarto html document with logo in it but its failing to display the logo in it even after successful rendering of the document. Quarto supporting docs I am referring is link
qmd header section I am using:
title: "Test Report"
author: "HQ"
format: 
  html:
    fontsize: 10pt
    code-overflow: wrap
embed-resources: true
smooth-scroll: true
code-tools:
    source: false
    toggle: false
    caption: none
toc: true
toc-location: right
echo: False
warning: False
message: false
jupyter: python3
theme:
  light: lux
  dark: slate
brand: brand/_brand.yml
include-in-header:
  - text: |
      <style>
      .cell-output-stdout code {
        word-break: break-wor !important;
        white-space: pre-wrap !important;
      }
      </style>

I have brand folder in this project where it is running and within that I am keeping the _brand.yml file and the logos png files

_brand.yml file content:
color:
  palette:
    blue: "#ddeaf1"
  background: blue
logo:
  medium:
    light: brand/logo-HQ.png
    dark: brand/logo-HQ-dark.png

Terminal log:
pandoc --output Test_branding.html
  to: html
  standalone: true
  embed-resources: true
  section-divs: true
  html-math-method: mathjax
  wrap: none
  default-image-extension: png
  toc: true

metadata
  document-css: false
  link-citations: true
  date-format: long
  lang: en
  title: Test Report
  author: HQ
  smooth-scroll: true
  toc-location: right
  message: false
  jupyter: python3
  theme:
    light: lux
    dark: slate
  brand: brand/_brand.yml
  fontsize: 10pt

Output created: Test_branding.html

I am not sure what is wrong with this as I am trying it for 1st time and have followed the documentation.
Update: Adding screenshot of the rendered document top page

Update After implementing Answer:
showing the navbar header but not the logo

Update:
About progress on logo/branding on standalone html documents in Quarto: https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/11627

It's not really clear from your example where you expect the logo to be shown. Can you add a complete minimal example? If I e.g. have a website project with a _quarto.yml which defines a navbar and a sidebar, then it works for me and the logo is shown in both.

@Jan I just want to place the logo at the top left corner of the html page. I am not really creating a website but just a html page document output of some analytics. I have not added anything else to this to create a logo. Other than that its just the python codes performing analytics on the data in the qmd file. Do I need to add anything else like _quarto.yml or some html css script to it ? Based on documentation I thought it was enough but I am naive to this so please excuse my ignorance.

One possibility is that you set up a website, using a _quarto.yml, see e.g. this example (GitHub code). In this sense you could define a navbar where the logo is top left and you could also define a sidebar and so on which refers to the logo. If you just want to have a single html page you may need css and so on because you have to define where the logo shall appear.

I could provide an answer with an example based on your provided code for a small website (using _quarto.yml). Would this be suitable for you? If not, what is your expectation on an answer? If you want to have a standalone document with css, you may need to provide more details within your question.

@Jan Yes that should work for me. It shouldn't be much of difference in logo if its just 1 standalone document or complete website. I am looking for the logo to go on the top of page on left corner. Please share an example in the answer if possible and meanwhile I will also update the post with the screenshot of the top page of rendered output.

@Jan if you need any more information then please let me know I would be happy to share. After the yaml headers in the qmd file goes on importing libraries and reading & processing data. That's all it is in the qmd file other than these branding & logo files.

About work on logo/branding for standalone quarto documents: https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/11627

You need to define html document content where the logo shall appear. A possibility is that you set up a _quarto.yml defining a project which has type: website and that you define a navbar. Then the logo will appear on the top left of the page. Below is an example building on top of your provided code where the brand definition is contained within the _quarto.yml and additionally there is a sidebar which also makes use of the logo.

_quarto.yml
project:
  type: website

website:
  title: "Simple Brand Example"
  navbar:
    title: "Demo for Brand and Logo"
  sidebar:
    search: true

brand: brand/_brand.yml

_brand.yml
color:
  palette:
    blue: "#ddeaf1"
  background: blue
logo:
  medium:
    light: brand/logo-HQ.png
    dark: brand/logo-HQ-dark.png

index.qmd
---
title: "Test Report"
author: "HQ"
format: 
  html:
    fontsize: 10pt
    code-overflow: wrap
embed-resources: true
smooth-scroll: true
code-tools:
    source: false
    toggle: false
    caption: none
toc: true
toc-location: right
echo: False
warning: False
message: false
jupyter: python3
theme:
  light: lux
  dark: slate
include-in-header:
  - text: |
      <style>
      .cell-output-stdout code {
        word-break: break-wor !important;
        white-space: pre-wrap !important;
      }
      </style>
---

## Overview

This is a document themed using [**brand.yml**](https://posit-dev.github.io/brand-yml/)

## Subheading

{{< lipsum 1 >}}

::: {.content-visible when-format="dashboard"}



:::


When we include _quarto.yml in the folder does is also start processing or takes in account of other qmd files as well ? I think that is what is happening. Getting an error because of other qmd files in folder. Let me remove other qmds from the folder and hopefully it will work then.

In the above example I only have the index.qmd within the folder.

It just ran successfully and it giving me the header but it is still not showing the logo in that. Adding the screenshot in the post

What is your Quarto version? (quarto --version)

Its quarto==1.5.57

brand.yml is only supported from 1.6 on (Release notes), please update and try again.

ohh I didn't know that. Thanks !! And I think it has created a folder with files. Is it possible to keep it as 1 file only instead of folder ?

Using a project I don't think so. Then you need another approach (also with the logos).

I have tried with couple of alternatives and now using one of them. They are like a hack & messy but might be useful in certain situation until there is a official work release on this.

This is what I am using by adding a logo Image on the top, there are several ways to do it based on your needs:
---
title: BrandName
title-block-banner: true 
format: 
  html:  
    grid:
      sidebar-width: 10px
      body-width: 900px
    fontsize: 10pt
    code-overflow: wrap
embed-resources: true
smooth-scroll: true
code-tools:
    source: false
    toggle: false
    caption: none
toc: true
toc-location: right
echo: False
warning: False
message: false
jupyter: python3
theme:
  light: lux
  dark: slate
include-in-header:
  - text: |
      <style>
      .cell-output-stdout code {
        word-break: break-wor !important;
        white-space: pre-wrap !important;
      }
      </style>
---


:::: {layout="[30,-40,30]"}

::: {#first-column}
![](logo/brand-logo.png)
:::

::: {#second-column}
**Analytics Report**

Date: `{python} datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")`

For: **user name**
:::

::::

---

Body text or any content you want

```{python}

```


This would place the logo on the very top
html:
    include-before-body: 
      text: |
        <img src="logo/brand-logo.png" width="180" height="100">
        <p style='text-align:center;font-size:80px;font-weight:900;'><u>BrandName</u></p>




